# How files in a lambda layer will be copied to the /opt/bin directory?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, imagemagick, aws-lambda-layers

I am working with a PDF to Image Conversion Project in AWS Lambda, but had some issues, since AWS lambda doesn't have the relevant binaries like `ImageMagick` in the environment, then I followed some links and StackOverflow question and put the relevant binaries as a layer, for the job I had to use `Ghostscript` compiled binaries.

The layer zip contain files like this

> GhostScript.zip > bin > gs

I have a wrapper library call `pdf2png` and It will execute a child process which do the convertion, the command this child process use is the above mentioned `gs` utitity, but **my issue is the path I mentioned for the utility is wrong, it throws an error saying,**

> Error: spawn /opt/bin/bin/gs ENOENT

So What I want to know is how will the lambda layer files be copied to the `/opt/bin/` directory? how should I replace the path?

Corresponding code,

```
gs()
    .batch()
    .nopause()
    .option('-r' + options.density)
  // .option('-dDownScaleFactor=2')
    .option('-dFirstPage=' + page)
    .option('-dLastPage=' + page)


    .executablePath('/opt/bin/bin/gs')


    .device('png16m')
    .output(output)
    .input(filepath)
    .exec(function (err, stdout, stderr) {
```

Answer (score 0):

The executable path in my case have to be like this

> ```
> .executablePath('/opt/bin/gs')
> ```

It has extracted the files in the `bin` folder inside the layer into the `/opt/bin/` folder directly.

Comment: If this is a public facing SaaS implementation, then you need to abide by the terms of the AGPL, you should check the licence and make sure you are compliant. This also is not a Ghostscript question.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand why this needs to adhere to AGPL license? is it because I use ImageMagick which is an opensource package or any other reason? I have zero knowledge about it.

Comment: Ghostscript is licenced under the AGPL (v3), if you use Ghostscript then you need to adhere to the provisions of the AGPL. ImageMagick uses its own licence, and you should make sure you adhere to the terms of that licence as well. If you are using any pieces of open source software you need to adhere to the terms of them all. If this is for personal use then the simplest solution is probably to open source your code, that pretty much always covers you, If its in any way commercial then you need to do the legwork and check the licences. You may need the help of a lawyer.